# Azure VM create from an image

Tags: azure

I have an existing VM in the East US reqion. I want to duplicate it in the West. I stop the vm and capture an image with the web interface and it creates a specialized image. I can also create a new vm but it won't let me change the location/region. Using the command line I try this:

```
azure vm create test-vm <image> -e --location "West US"
```

And gives this error:

The location or affinity group East US of the storage account where the source image Windshaft-os-2015-12-10 resides is not in the same location or affinity group as the specified cloud service. The source image must reside in a storage account that has the same affinity group or location as the cloud service West US.

Is there a way to move it to another region?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot move a storage account from one region to another, but you can move any blob from one storage account to another that is located in another region.

This page explains how to move a VHD from one account to another : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/migrate-azure-virtual-machines-between-storage-accounts/

Hope this helps.

Julien